# cmake on Android (NDK): meaning of -D?

Tags: cmake

I use NDK and cmake for my Android app. Typical cmake commande is like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDROID_NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI=x86 -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24
```

I wonder what is the meaning of the -D ?

Does cmake commands work without -D ?

```
cmake -CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDROID_NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -ANDROID_ABI=x86 -ANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24
```

What is the impact on the final build?

Thanks

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html

Comment: @Michael Thanks. How to be sure that I compile in release mode? (to build a non debuggable version) Any special flag? Thanks.

Comment: `-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html (that is assuming you're using a single configuration generator; otherwise you'd need to use `cmake --build project_build_dir --config Release` (and equivalent for e.g. `--install`) to tell cmake which configuration to build.